# Trigger an event on pre-signed URL expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below is an example of event notification on object creation:

```
s3EventObjectCreated:
    handler: src/handlers/postProcess
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: 'bucketName'
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: 'files/'
          existing: true
```

How can I create event notification on pre-signed URL expiration?

So, If pre-signed URL expired it should trigger an event and call my lambda function.

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ do you wish to receive this notification? There might be a better way to architect your app that doesn't need such notification. For example, you can generate the pre-signed URL precisely when it is required, rather than keeping it for later use. If you can tell us more about your situation, we will be able to provide better advice.

Comment: So, the workflow should be, Generate pre-signed URL and create one document in `dynamoDB`. Client will upload a document using a pre-signed URL, if success, I need to update document in dynamo DB. If client failed to upload the document within expiration time(pre-signed URL expired), I need to delete document from dynamo DB.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to regularly delete all documents that are in a "non-actioned" state and older than a certain period. Or, add the expiration time to the document and use that time to determine whether to delete.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein makes a good point.  Additionally, bear in mind that a request involving a pre-signed URL only needs to *start* before the URL expires, not *finish* before... so there is a race condition to be aware of if the upload begins immediately before the expiration but finishes after.  The upload will succeed if it starts before expiration, however long it takes to finish.

Comment: FYI, we have decided to generate a pre-signed URL, Create a document in dynamo DB only after upload gets done. So, in a way, we do not worry about the unused dynamo DB document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-signed URLs are generated on the client side, without involving Amazon S3. When generating pre-signed URLs the provided credentials are uses to create a signature which is valid for a certain amount of time. This signature can be used to make requests later on. When making the actual request AWS checks whether the signature was made with authorized credentials and whether it is still valid.

Because the signatures are generated on the client side, you can't let AWS trigger anything once they expire.

To trigger actions when pre-signed URLs expire you'd need some additional logic. You could for example ensure that you store an item for each pre-signed URL in DynamoDB and use [DynamoDB's TTL feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) to trigger a Lambda function based on the DynamoDB stream event caused by the removal of the item from DynamoDB, once your pre-signed URL expires.

Comment: Although I understand what you're trying to say, it's not *DynamoDB's TTL feature* that actually triggers the Lambda function. Whenever an item expires, it will send an event of type `REMOVE` to a DynamoDB stream which may then be consumed by a Lambda function. I know you know it, but I am just pointing it out as it may confuse users who don't understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Now that I think of it, that'd maybe not be the best solution as AWS doesn't guarantee timely removal of items in DynamoDB whose TTL expired.

Comment: True, but I can't think of anything else myself. Initially I would adopt the same solution. Delay queues could also work for short-lived pre-signed URLs (up to 15 minutes). Anyways, I doubt it needs to be a real-time thingy, OP probably just wants to see a dashboard/list of URLs that were not used. I would still go with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. According to the [AWS S3 Notifications Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), AWS S3 publishes notifications for the following events only:

- A new object created event
- An object removal event
- Restore object events
- A Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) object lost event

It seems you want your lambda to get executed on S3 pre signed url expiration. There is a work around. I bet your S3 URL's must be having a pre configured expiry time.

1. If your expiry time is less than or equal to 15 minutes then you could use SQS Delayed Queues. Whenever you generate the S3 URL you just push a message to SQS with a delay of `expiry_time` and when the message becomes visible in SQS after that delayed time, it triggers your lambda.
2. If your expiry time is beyond 15 minutes, you can look into options of [running lambda on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html). Or, you could write your own scheduler using [bull.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull-arena) and trigger lambda when the job executes.